# How to send a request containing a NodeJs image?

Tags: node.js, post, request, upload, fetch

I'd like to know how I could add an image to a POST request and turn it into a MultiPart request with Fetch NodeJs.

I've searched but most of what I see is simple JS without the use of Node. I've tried to make some buffer but nothing work.